# Multiple entry points in Vite

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a Vue2 project with Webpack, and I'm trying to switch from Webpack to Vite.

In `webpack.common.js`, I have multiple entry points:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        appSchool: './resources/school/app.js',
        appStudent: './resources/student/app.js',
        appAuth: './resources/auth/app.js'
    },
    ...
}
```

How do I write this in `vite.config.js`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Vite uses Rollup under the hood, and you can configure Rollup through [`build.rollupOptions`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-rollupoptions), and then [Rollup's `input` option](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#input):

```js
// vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        appSchoool: fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/school/index.html', import.meta.url)),
        appStudent: fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/student/index.html', import.meta.url)),
        appAuth: fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/auth/index.html', import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Note the entry points refer to `index.html` files, which themselves link to the `app.js` in their corresponding directories (e.g., `./resources/student/index.html` contains `<script src="./app.js">`). The `input` config also accepts the `app.js` file directly, but no HTML would be generated.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-multiple-entry-points?file=vite.config.js)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to tony19's answer, you can also just use `resolve` to generate the paths, makes the code a lot more readable:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        appSchool: resolve(__dirname, 'resources/school/index.html'),
        appStudent: resolve(__dirname, 'resources/student/index.html'),
        appAuth: resolve(__dirname, 'resources/auth/index.html'),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

See [the official docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) for a multipage app.

Comment: The thing is, `__dirname` won't work in es modules.

Comment: Well it works for Vitejs. See their official docs.

Comment: do not forget `base: "./"`

Comment: @s.meijer `import * as path from 'node:path'; let __dirname = path.dirname(import.meta.url.substring('file://'.length));`