# Multiple entry points in Vite for dev server mode?

Tags: vite

Is it possible to get multiple html entry points to work in Vite when running it as a dev server (with `vite --host`)? I'm currently using this post's solution [Multiple entry points in Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70522494/multiple-entry-points-in-vite), but it only works for when building the site to a `dist` folder.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming here with same question. Taken from Vite [guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build#multi-page-app)

> Suppose you have the following source code structure:
>
> ```
> ├── package.json
> ├── vite.config.js
> ├── index.html
> ├── main.js
> └── nested
>     ├── index.html
>     └── nested.js
> ```
>
> During dev, simply navigate or link to /nested/ - it works as expected, just like for a normal static file server.

Comment: Also, it turns out the trailing slash is important. Navigating to `/nested` didn't work for me, but `/nested/` worked.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I face same thing, trailing slash is important.